# Python Argparse strict variable name

Tags: python, argparse

I try to understand a functionality (or bug ?) of python's argparse.

Here, my simple code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="%(prog)s [--start]", add_help=False)
parser.add_argument("--start", help="Start prog", action="store_true")

arguments  = parser.parse_args()
start_fpc  = arguments.start

print arguments
```

When I execute this script, both `start` and `star` arguments are accepted:

```
[ rsenet  2015-08-28 12:39:50] /tmp
$ python test.py --star
Namespace(start=True)

[ rsenet  2015-08-28 13:59:16] /tmp
$ python test.py --start
Namespace(start=True)
```

Any idea why? If yes, is it possible to disable this function?

Comment: Seems to be due to https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argument-abbreviations-prefix-matching but there's no mention there of how to prevent it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable abbreviation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750802/disable-abbreviation)

Comment: Yes, it's comming from abbreviation but not possible to disable it in python 2.X :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable `allow_abbrev` option, which [was introduced](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/99302634d756/) in v3.5.

Excerpt from [argparse doc](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Doc/library/argparse.rst):

> - allow_abbrev_ - Allows long options to be abbreviated if the
>      abbreviation is unambiguous. (default: `True`)

This should help:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="%(prog)s [--start]",
                                 allow_abbrev=False,
                                 add_help=False)
```

Comment: @Andrejs I want to use the allow_abbrev in python2.7.x. How can I specify the same?

Comment: @Karthick Switch to 3.5, or develop your own argument parser.