# How to stop argparse from accepting abbreviated "long name" flags? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument("--dog")
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--dog'], dest='dog', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> args = parser.parse_args(["--do", "fido"])
>>> args
Namespace(dog='fido')
```

This seems like a bug. I would have expected it to not recognize the argument. How can I stop this from happening?

Edit: [apparently this is documented behavior...](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argument-abbreviations-prefix-matching)

Comment: [Another option for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39479562/2877364) (posting here since I'm not sure how widely `@` notation will carry on SO).

Comment: You could steal the `argparse.py` file from a 3.5 version.  Everything in the 3.5 should work in 2.7 with one exception, a line that uses `yield from get_subactions()`.  You'll want to retain the 2.7 version for that.  `argparse` uses just one file, so it is easy to the stock version with a custom one.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=False)
```

Per [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#allow-abbrev).  Requires Python 3.5 or higher.

Comment: Ah, this would be perfect, but I am using Python 2.7. It seems this option is not available to me. I've updated the tags in my question to reflect this.